# How can I optimize this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have 3 tables on an Oracle context, let's call them `t1, t2, t3` which have the following structure :

- `t1 : t1_ID, t1_name, ...`
- `t2 : t1_ID, t3_name, ...`
- `t3 : t3_name, randomCol1, randomCol2, randomCol3, ...`

What I want is a query that give me a result like this :

> t0_name | randomCol

So i made this query :

```
      SELECT t1.t1_name, t3.randomCol1 AS randomCol
      FROM t1
      JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_ID=t2.t1_ID
      JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_name=t3.t3_name
      WHERE t3.randomCol1 LIKE '_%'
    UNION
      SELECT t1.t1_name, t3.randomCol2 AS randomCol
      FROM t1
      JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_ID=t2.t1_ID
      JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_name=t3.t3_name
      WHERE t3.randomCol2 LIKE '_%'
    UNION
      SELECT t1.t1_name, t3.randomCol3 AS randomCol
      FROM t1
      JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_ID=t2.t1_ID
      JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_name=t3.t3_name
      WHERE t3.randomCol3 LIKE '_%'
```

Because I wanted all values of randomCols starting with `_` in a single column, paired with the t1_name linked to them.
To give more intel, randomCol1 and randomCol2 are almost the same (they are both not null at the same times and have almost the same values), while randomCol3 is usually null.

---

I know that this is awful in term of performance, so I tried to improve it.

Therefore I searched on the web various ways to optimize this solution (like using UNION ALL and stuff) but nothing gave me the exact result that I want.

So my question is the following :
**Do you have any idea of how I can optimize this query ?**

Regards

Comment: Do we really have to call the tables `t0, t01, t1`?

Comment: No, I changed the original names for privacy, but if you have a better naming idea, I'd be glad to adopt it :)

Comment: I think you need to use UNPIVOT, I'll see if I can come up with the SQL for it. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Actually the query runs on Oracle, I tagged it but didn't mention in the body.
Gonna update it sorry

(It seemed to be that though)

Comment: Sure you need to desensitize the code, but something like `t1, t2, t3` would be a bit easier to read.

Comment: @JulienGanis, when you say *with values starting with '_' in a single column* do you mean that only one of them should start with `_` (and the other shouldn't)?

Comment: No, all the values in the second column should start with `_`

Comment: @JulienGanis, BTW does your query really work for you ? because the `_` should be escaped, something like this- `WHERE t3.randomCol1 LIKE '\_%' escape '\'`

Comment: Which version of Oracle? `UNPIVOT` (as used in Andy Nichols' answer) was introduced in Oracle 11g.

Comment: @Cade in the original query it's a `$` so there is no problem. Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: @MarkBannister It's Oracle10g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible variant:

```
  select * from
  (SELECT t1.t1_name, 
          case l.l
              when 1 then t3.randomCol1 
              when 2 then t3.randomCol2 
              when 3 then t3.randomCol3
          end AS randomCol
   FROM (select level l from dual connect by level <= 3) l
   CROSS JOIN t1
   JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_ID=t2.t1_ID
   JOIN t3 ON t2.t3_name=t3.t3_name
   WHERE '_' in (substr(t3.randomCol1,1,1),
                 substr(t3.randomCol2,1,1),
                 substr(t3.randomCol3,1,1))
  ) where randomCol like '_%'
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do the `union` or `union all`, Oracle may be executing the subqueries multiple times. You can fix this with `unpivot` or by using a `cross join` as follows:

```
SELECT t1.t1_name,
       (case when n.n = 1 then t3.randomCol1
             when n.n = 2 then t3.randomCol2
             when n.n = 3 then t3.randomCol3
        end) AS randomCol
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.t1_ID=t2.t1_ID JOIN
     t3
     ON t2.t3_name=t3.t3_name cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual union all select 3) n
where n.n = 1 and LEFT(t3.randomCol1, 1) = '_' or
      n.n = 2 and LEFT(t3.randomCol2, 1) = '_' or
      n.n = 3 and LEFT(t3.randomCol3, 1) = '_'
```

I replaced the `like` with `left` because `'_'` is a wilcard for `like`.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server it would be something like

```
SELECT t0_name, randomCol
FROM (SELECT t0_name, randomCol1, randomCol2, etc)
      FROM t0
      JOIN t01 ON t0.t0_ID=t1.t0_ID
      JOIN t1 ON t01.t1_name=t1.t1_name) p
UNPIVOT (randomCol FOR items in (randomCol1, randomCol2, etc)) unpvt
WHERE randomCol like '_%'
```

and I think it would be the same in Oracle: See [this article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)